# How to replace strings in MySQL that contains backslashes

Tags: mysql, search, replace, backslash

I try to replace strings in MySQL table from:

```
href=\"example.com\"
```

to

```
href=\"https://example.com\"
```

I know correct query how to search and update string, it is works perfectly, until I try to change string with backslashes. Nothing doesn't work:

```
UPDATE `articles` SET `text` = REPLACE(`text`, 'href=\\\\"example.com\\\\"', 'href=\\\\"https://example.com\\\\"') WHERE `text` LIKE '%href=\\\\"example.com\\\\"%'
```

Of course I tried different variants and combinations with escaped and not escaped backslaches, with clause WHERE and without it. These all variants doesn't work. Nothing changes at all!

Also, when I pre-run this query in PHPMyAdmin (section "Find and Replace"), it correctly finds all articles that contains **href=\"example.com\"**, but Replaced string shows me the same content as Original String.

My CMS, which has also built-in function for search and replace strings, also can't change strings with backslashes.

I'm totally stuck with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put too much backslash on the replace search string so the string is not found. double backslash are stored as one backslash in the table, so you need to use 2x backslash when replacing the string and 4x backslash when doing search in where clause.
see demo here; http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1e0eb/1

```
update articles
set text =
REPLACE(`text`, 'href=\\"example.com\\"', 'href=\\"https://example.com\\"')
where text like '%href=\\\\"example.com\\\\"%'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the query you want to update;

```
UPDATE `articles` 
SET `text` = REPLACE(`text`, 'href=\\"example.com\\"', 'href=\\"https://example.com\\"') 
WHERE `text` LIKE '%href=\\\\"example.com\\\\"%'
```